# How to change filename download Export Execl in AngulaJS?

Tags: angularjs

I see code in Codepend. But i want to change filename Excel download. Pls help me

```
  Link :https://codepen.io/marco27384/pen/pboLyx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify the download attribute of the href. That's not possible with setting the window.location.href in the current code. Instead, here's an example which creates a new anchor tag, sets up the download and href attributes. Finally the link is clicked and we have our downloaded file, myname.xls

```js
$timeout(function() {
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = exportHref
  a.download = 'myname.xls'
  a.click()
  // $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100);
  // trigger download
}, 100)
```